# GoogleMap moveCamera or animateCamera according to LatLngBounds is not accurate

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Im having some doubts regarding the accuracy of moveCamera and animateCamera with CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(). Im comparing a LatLngBounds object im creating and sending as a parameter to moveCamera/animateCamera (CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds()), to *map*.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds in onCameraChange() event or even GoogleMap.CancelableCallback#onFinish(). **They do not match**.
Did someone encountered this issue ? Is this a bug ?

My code is :

```
final LatLngBounds boundingBox = MapUtils.getBoundingBox(mCurrLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrLocation.getLongitude(), mCurrRadius);
    
try {
    if (animate) {
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundingBox, 0),
            new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    if (!boundingBox.equals(map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds)) {
                            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundingBox, 0));
                        }
                    }
                    
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }
                });
    } else {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundingBox, 0));
    }
}
```

Please ignore the way im comparing the 2 objects here (equals). i also debugged the code and inspected the 2 objects and saw that they do not match -

moveCamera :

> **boundingBox -**
>
> > LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (32.08455383290544,34.773394063736845), northeast=lat/lng: (32.09730731777191,34.788375176773286)}
>
> **map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds -**
>
> > LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (32.084496299473756,34.77339383214712), northeast=lat/lng: (32.09736452396455,34.78837497532368)}

animateCamera :

> **boundingBox -**
>
> > LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (40.70798493778415,-74.01434069136418), northeast=lat/lng: (40.72072004852845,-73.99760391411343)}
>
> **map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds -**
>
> > LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (40.70798500292429,-74.01539381593466), northeast=lat/lng: (40.72071968970514,-73.99655096232891)}

Comment: I know it's an old thread but I have the same problem and still no solution is available to this bug. I've tested it on a dozen different phone and this only happens on a Samsung GT-I9500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a combination of both `bug && !bug`.

For a bug description, see this: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5353

Basically you will have differences at 5th or 6th decimal place.

The other issue is that when you send `LatLngBounds` to one of these functions, the resulting `LatLngBounds` will be new that fits the screen exactly and your original will be inside it.

Comment: Thanks. i guess im calculating the boundingBox assuming the map is a square. and its not really.

Comment: i was wrong in my previous answer. i am calculating correctly the bounding box.  see my additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with animateCamera and LatLngBounds. The method doesnt move the camera accurately to the expected box. How do i know that ? I verified that by adding the following code :

```
private LatLngBounds mBoundingBox;
private boolean mCameraAnimated;

public void setCurrentLocation(Location currentLocation, String radius, boolean animate) {
    mCurrLocation = currentLocation;
    mCurrRadius = MapUtils.getRadiusDecimalValue(radius);
    mBoundingBox = MapUtils.getBoundingBox(mCurrLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrLocation.getLongitude(), mCurrRadius);
    mCameraAnimated = animate;

    if (animate) {
            mEventMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mBoundingBox, 0));
    } else {
            mEventMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mBoundingBox, 0));
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    // This ugly solution was added because there is a bug with camera animate which doesn't move to the correct bounding box.
    if (mBoundingBox != null && !mBoundingBox.equals(mEventMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds)) {
        LatLngBounds originalBoundingBox = mBoundingBox;
        mBoundingBox = null;
        if (mCameraAnimated) {
            mCameraAnimated = false;
            mEventMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(originalBoundingBox, 0));
            return;
        }
    } ...
```

Now, after the additional moveCamera, the camera positions itself correctly.
The new problem is that sometimes onCameraChange is not being triggered by this additional moveCamera and therefore im not executing my actual onCameraChange code (marked by '...').

Comment: What is `MapUtils`, where did you get it from?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky its my own utils class. irrelevant to the question.